# 2 table copies after from

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Why does not this select work in Oracle despite working in PostgreSQL (The third sum should be the same like in: select sum(salary) from employees) ?:

```
select e1.employee_id, e1.department_id, e1.manager_id, e1.salary,
sum(e2.salary), sum(e3.salary)
from employees e1, employees e2, employees e3
where e1.department_id=e2.department_id
group by e1.employee_id, e1.department_id, e1.manager_id, e1.salary  
order by 1,2;
```

It works in PostgreSQL, but not here. In Oracle works only one copy e2 without any constraints (when e1 is the original table and is grouped by its primary key) after from:

```
 select e1.employee_id, e1.department_id, e1.manager_id, e1.salary,
    sum(e2.salary)
    from employees e1, employees e2
    where e1.department_id=e2.department_id
    group by e1.employee_id, e1.department_id, e1.manager_id, e1.salary  
    order by 1,2;
```

or even without where as the whole sum for each record of the first table (NO CONSTRAINTS here):

```
 select e1.employee_id, e1.department_id, e1.manager_id, e1.salary,
    sum(e2.salary)
    from employees e1, employees e2
    group by e1.employee_id, e1.department_id, e1.manager_id, e1.salary  
    order by 1,2;
```

Of course, I know other alternative selects such as:

```
select employee_id, department_id, manager_id, salary, 
sum(salary) over (partition by department_id) as suma,
sum(salary) over ()
from employees order by 2,3;
```

or with subselects:

```
select employee_id, department_id, manager_id, salary, 
(select sum(e2.salary) from employees e2
where e2.department_id=e1.department_id) as suma1,
(select sum(e2.salary) from employees e2) as suma2
from employees e1 order by 1,2;
```

Do you know a way of doing more than one table copies in Oracle?

Comment: You *need* to explain the purpose of the query to begin with. In plain English. What are `sum(e2.salary)` and `sum(e3.salary)` supposed to achieve?

Comment: It is an academic example, they are just to be there, with some conditions they can be different sums, but in third select they are just sums of all salaries.

Answer (score 1):

in your first query you create a full cartesian product since you did not set any constraints to match between the tables

Comment: These are copies of employees, and one table has "group by" a primary key, and other copies should be connected to one record of first table as the whole ones or cut by conditions after where. It works in PostgreSQL.

Comment: okay after your last edit there is still no "link" between e3 and the other tables

Comment: One copy without costraints works as I edited my question. In PostgreSQL it works with two or even more copies.

Comment: You can do the correct select with one table copy e2 and one original table e1 after from even without constraint on the condition that on the first table primary key you have group by. I asked why I could not do it with two table copies eg. e1,e2,e3 as in other databases and maybe there is a simple hint to enable this copies after from. Of course, if you explain me this problem, I can remove my critic points. If you still do not understand then ask me more, please.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but you seem to be missing the point of the Q just like I did.

Comment: seems like it - got to check this tomorrow